# keypad tone will get very loud and then return to normal while typing in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am developing an iOS chat application and found a strange bug when i type text on keyboard then tone will get very loud and then return to normal after 5-6 tap while typing in iPhone. I googled much but did not find any solution :(

Please help me to get rid out of this issue.

Thank you

Comment: are you using any audio file for button tap?

Comment: No, i am not playing any audio file while tapping on keyboard.